# How can I replace a specific pattern in notepad++/visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio. Throughout my application in the SCSS code, I am converting all the `px` to `rem` units through a function.

For example:

`padding: 16px 32px 48px --> padding: rem(16) rem(32) rem(48)` which evaluates to `padding: 1rem 2rem 3rem`.

Now for some reason I need to convert all `rem` units back to `px` units.
For that I want to identify the pattern `rem(xyz)` and replace it with `xyz px`.

Example:

```
.wrapper{
    font-size: rem(40);
    .content{
        padding: rem(20) rem(10) rem(30);
    }
}

.wrapper{
    font-size: 40px;
    .content{
        padding: 20px 10px 30px;
    }
}
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this using the Find & Replace tool in Notepad++ or Visual Studio.

`rem\((.*?)\)` --> This regular expression identifies the pattern. 
I was trying to use the same captured group and replace it in this way 
`\((.*?)\)px`, with no success.

Comment: formatting & minor wording edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find,

```
rem\((\d+)\)
```

and replace with,

```
$1px
```

where `rem` matches literal `rem` and `\(` matches literal `(` then `(\d+)` captures one or more digits and captures in group1, which will be used while replacing the matched text with same number and finally `\)` matches a literal `)`

In replacement text, `$1` represents text captured in group1 and hence replaces the matched text with number and `px` like you wanted.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wSKldr/1)**

Comment: $1px is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match digits without a decimal value you could use a capturing group to keep the digits between the parenthesis:

```
\brem\((\d+)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E6UpM3/2)

And replace with:

`$1px`

If you also want to match decimals, you could use:

```
\brem\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)\)
```

- `\brem` Word boundary and match `rem`
- `\(` Match `(` char
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits followed by an optional part that matches a dot and digit
  - `|` Or
  - `\.\d+` Match a dot and 1+ digits
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\)` Match `)` char

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nRCoLv/1)